# Visual Studio Code can't find file

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, zip

*Total newbie here*   I am trying to open a folder in Visual Studio Code but it can't seem to see the folder. It was a zipped file which i can see and open in my computer files but when I try to open through VSC it isn't there. Any ideas?
I clicked on 'Open Folder' in VSC.
When i double clicked on the unzipped python folder it said there was nothing there.
I was expecting something to open in VSC

Comment: For start `Visual Studio` (from the question) and `Visual Studio Code` (from the tag) are different IDEs

Comment: should all be Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "zipped folder" is just a .zip file. It isn't actually a folder on the file system. It just *looks* like a folder in the operating system file browser. VS Code only opens real file system folders. It can't see "into" a zip file to extract files inside it. (same for most applications).

To open a zipped folder/file in VS code, you'll have to unzip the folder first, or extract the specific file you want to open. (Right click, Extract All, pick a place to unzip it to).

Comment: Since this worked for you, please Accept this answer by clicking the grey check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Total newbie here too !
Can you share with us some graphical details?

From what I understood you tried to "Open Folder" from Microsfot Visual Studio´s startup window, and nothing showed up?
[If you cant see your solution, go to View > Solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgFAv.png)

Add some empty TXT files and see if your VS gets them

Comment: I got it sorted. Thanks for answering!!

Comment: Im glad you got it solved ;) !

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This type of commentary is better provided as a comment to a question/answer rather than as an answer itself. I know you are unable to provide comments yet, but there are [reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)